# Publish Test Results task test name is not correct

Tags: azure-devops

In my trx file there are 3 test cases. The UnitTestResult name is below

[image: Different Test Name]

Code:

```
<Results>
    <UnitTestResult executionId="a009dca9-9a9c-45c6-966e-ce83b6a8f4d0" testId="c9427cd3-1949-4163-f8e9-3d620e7b7c04" testName="CampaignAdGroupCreationMSANAdCreatorSuite" computerName="71986a60c000008" duration="00:03:23.4530000" startTime="2022-11-17T00:20:46.3170000+00:00" endTime="2022-11-17T00:24:09.7700000+00:00" testType="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b" outcome="Failed" testListId="8c84fa94-04c1-424b-9868-57a2d4851a1d" relativeResultsDirectory="a009dca9-9a9c-45c6-966e-ce83b6a8f4d0" />
    <UnitTestResult executionId="f61b0324-afe2-4b5a-b48d-e6fc2dbee4b0" testId="178fc87e-7321-761c-6004-c0824a26eaa4" testName="CampaignAdGroupCreationMSANAdCreatorSuite.should be able to apply effect to image added to an ad in create campaign workflow" computerName="71986a60c000008" duration="00:01:52.7160000" startTime="2022-11-17T00:21:15.6250000+00:00" endTime="2022-11-17T00:23:08.3410000+00:00" testType="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b" outcome="Failed" testListId="8c84fa94-04c1-424b-9868-57a2d4851a1d" relativeResultsDirectory="f61b0324-afe2-4b5a-b48d-e6fc2dbee4b0">
    <UnitTestResult executionId="a5a4451b-675c-47ef-80f3-fba4a13c9b56" testId="5db0478b-94a4-a31f-ee72-883dbd15bb96" testName="CampaignAdGroupCreationMSANAdCreatorSuite.should be able to apply effect to image added to an ad in create adgroup workflow" computerName="71986a60c000008" duration="00:01:01.2260000" startTime="2022-11-17T00:23:08.3420000+00:00" endTime="2022-11-17T00:24:09.5680000+00:00" testType="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b" outcome="Failed" testListId="8c84fa94-04c1-424b-9868-57a2d4851a1d" relativeResultsDirectory="a5a4451b-675c-47ef-80f3-fba4a13c9b56">
</Results>
```

But in the 'Tests' tab, the test name are the same.
[image: Same name in Tests tab]

Click each one, the callstack and error message are correct.

Here is the test defination in the TRX file:

```
<TestDefinitions>
    <UnitTest name="CampaignAdGroupCreationMSANAdCreatorSuite" storage="parentsuite" id="c9427cd3-1949-4163-f8e9-3d620e7b7c04">
      <Execution id="a009dca9-9a9c-45c6-966e-ce83b6a8f4d0" />
      <TestMethod codeBase="ParentSuite" adapterTypeName="executor://mochatestexecutor/" className="ParentSuite" name="CampaignAdGroupCreationMSANAdCreatorSuite" />
    </UnitTest>

    <UnitTest name="CampaignAdGroupCreationMSANAdCreatorSuite" storage="campaign-adgroup-creation-selenium" id="178fc87e-7321-761c-6004-c0824a26eaa4">
      <Execution id="f61b0324-afe2-4b5a-b48d-e6fc2dbee4b0" />
      <TestMethod codeBase="campaign-adgroup-creation-selenium" adapterTypeName="executor://mochatestexecutor/" className="CampaignAdGroupCreationMSANAdCreatorSuite" name="should be able to apply effect to image added to an ad in create campaign workflow" />
    </UnitTest>

    <UnitTest name="CampaignAdGroupCreationMSANAdCreatorSuite" storage="campaign-adgroup-creation-selenium" id="5db0478b-94a4-a31f-ee72-883dbd15bb96">
      <Execution id="a5a4451b-675c-47ef-80f3-fba4a13c9b56" />
      <TestMethod codeBase="campaign-adgroup-creation-selenium" adapterTypeName="executor://mochatestexecutor/" className="CampaignAdGroupCreationMSANAdCreatorSuite" name="should be able to apply effect to image added to an ad in create adgroup workflow" />
    </UnitTest>
</TestDefinitions>
```

Could you please help to look?
Thanks.

The Tests tab was expected to show the correct test name.

Comment: Will the problem happen in a brand new test?

Comment: No chance to verify. Now I changed the version to 'publish test result' v1.*. This error occurred in v2.*.

Comment: Glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: It is just a workaround. The issue still exists in V2.*. Anyway, I can get the correct result now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded 'Publish test result' from V2 to V1.*, then I get the correct test list. It is just a workaround.